Has the flight deck access protocol changed after Germanwings 9525?
After 9/11, the flight decks were redesigned so you couldn't get in without a code, but whoever's on the flight deck could lock out everybody for 5 minutes.
A few years ago, a copilot locked out the pilot, and crashed the plane.
Since then, was the flight deck door design modified so that the pilot can always get in?
I realize this could allow a hijacker to coerce  the captain when he goes in the cabin, but that would prevent a crash.

The current flight deck door technology is explained in that answer, there is no difference between "cabin crew" and a pilot who left the flight deck in that regard. For protocols, see What is the two-person cockpit rule, as of February 2020? and What safety rule replaced the now-rescinded two-person rule (after Germanwings 9525)?

To answer directly your question, collecting information provided by @Bianfable:

The cabin access has not changed, at least officially. A crew member (commercial or flight crew member) can enter the flight deck with a code. This works well in case of pilots incapacitation.
However this possibility could be used by a criminal to coerce a flight attendant into opening the door, so there is a possibility for the flight deck crew to oppose this access each time the code is used.
Indeed a suicidal pilot could use this denial procedure to block the door. If a safety procedure existed to open the door in spite of the flight deck crew opposing it, it is obvious it wouldn't be disclosed to the public.

Instead the rule for a single person in the flight deck has changed. See What is the two-person cockpit rule, as of February 2020?. This change can prevent a suicidal pilot to crash the plane, by not allowing them to be alone in the flight deck, giving the possibility to the other crew member to open the flight deck door.


